# Create a gradient for an image

Tags: css

I've following image and trying to create gradient for that. I'm very beginner to gradient learning so please help me to get the css for this image. The work is more appreciated.[image]

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks I want css for that image.

Comment: @Sanganabasu Your question is badly written, so no one knows what *exactly* you want. Also you do not show, what you tried to do since now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jnuad/)

```
background: #2ea2f5;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #2ea2f5 0%, #2ea2f5 50%, #0089f3 50%, #0089f3 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2ea2f5), color-stop(50%,#2ea2f5), color-stop(50%,#0089f3), color-stop(100%,#0089f3));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #2ea2f5 0%,#2ea2f5 50%,#0089f3 50%,#0089f3 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #2ea2f5 0%,#2ea2f5 50%,#0089f3 50%,#0089f3 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #2ea2f5 0%,#2ea2f5 50%,#0089f3 50%,#0089f3 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #2ea2f5 0%,#2ea2f5 50%,#0089f3 50%,#0089f3 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2ea2f5', endColorstr='#0089f3',GradientType=0 );
```

If you want to create more gradients, refer to this source, will make your life much much easier

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/